# Python vlc bindings & raspberry pi HW acceleration

Tags: python, vlc

I managed to install vlc on raspberry pi 2 with hardware acceleration as described here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=59814&sid=65d833a90f1ee134cb57523599e1c8aa

and I am able to run videos using HW acceleration with no problems after adjusting the following settings in vlc gui:

[image: vlc settings for HW acceleration]

However, when I use python vlc binding to play a video in a tkinter frame,the video is sluggish (no HW acceleration), and I get the following error:

```
[0291ea18] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
../../../include/vlc_xlib.h:46:vlc_xlib_init: Xlib not initialized for threads.
This process is probably using LibVLC incorrectly.
Pass "--no-xlib" to libvlc_new() to fix this.
[6e500c78] vdpau_display vout display error: Xlib not initialized for threads
[6e500c78] xcb_xv vout display error: no available XVideo adaptor
../../include/vlc_xlib.h:46:vlc_xlib_init: Xlib not initialized for threads.
This process is probably using LibVLC incorrectly.
Pass "--no-xlib" to libvlc_new() to fix this.
[6e50d110] glx gl error: Xlib not initialized for threads
[swscaler @ 0x6e513b60] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb565le.
```

I am using vlc binding with tkinter. My vlc instance in the python code looks like this:

```
Instance = vlc.Instance(['--codec=omxil','--vout=omxil-vout','--input-repeat=-1', 
                     '--no-video-title-show', '--fullscreen', '--mouse-hide-timeout=0'])
```

So how can I play HW accelerated videos from python using vlc?

Comment: To start it looks like you don't have `Xlib` installed. Have you tried installing it?